# PHP - Dynamic rounding numbers to nearest million, hundred thousand, or thousand

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a dynamic rounding function in PHP

```
If the number is above a billion. 1,688,848,837 --> 1,688,000,000 (round to nearest million)
If the number is in the hundred millions. 688,848,837 --> 688,000,000 (round to nearest million)
If the number is in the tens of millions. 88,848,837 --> 88,000,000 (round to nearest million)
If the number is in the millions. 8,848,837 --> 8,000,000 (round to nearest million)
If the number is in the hundred thousands. 173,293 --> 173,000 (round to nearest thousand)
If the number is in the thousands 1,232 --> 1,000 (round to nearest hundred)
If the number is in the hundreds 123 --> 100 (round to nearest hundred)
If the number is in the tens 67 --> 70 (round to nearest ten)
If the number is less than 10, don't round
```

Here is what I have so far. My approach is janky... what should I do?

```
<?php 
$number = //insert number here
$number = floatval($number);
$roundLength = strlen($number);
$roundValues = array("17" => "6", "16" => "6", "15" => "6", "14" => "6", "13" => "6", "12" => "6", "11" => "6", "10" => "6", "9" => "6", "8" => "6", "7" => "6", "6" => "6", "5" => "4", "4" => "4", "3" => "3", "2" => "2", "1" => "1");
$roundLengthNumber = $roundValues[$roundLength];
$number = round($number , $roundValues[$roundLength]);
?>
```

Comment: Give an example of some values for `$number` in your code and what results you get.  The second arg to `round` is the decimal precision.  So 17 would be `X.xxxxxx`.

Comment: The implementation you wrote isn't all that bad and I'm not sure if there's a shorter way to do this rounding as you have very specific rules (e.g. it's not rounding billions to the nearest billion, but million instead). You could of course wrap this in a object oriented approach and write a unit test for it to have some reassurance and cleaner code.